# Get subsection of curved path in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have very long path (around 20k pixels). I just want to show the user subsection of the path that is equal user's screen width. Problem I'm facing is that my path is a curved line and while using `PathMeasure.getSegment()` I'm getting shorter path than screen width. My guess is that it is because of curved lines. `PathMeasure.length` returns 27k length.

In the image you can see 3 results of `PathMeasure.getSegment()`:

[image]

As you can see `PathMeasure.getSegment()` for straight path returns correct size.
How can I achieve the same result with curved path?

Comment: I gather that you want to calculate a segment with a certain _width_, so that you can fill the entire screen, end-to-end, rather than calculating a segment with a certain path length. Is that correct?

Comment: @greeble31 this is exactly what i want to achieve.

Comment: `PathMeasure` does not support this; that's not what it was designed for. There is no API that I'm aware of that can segment a `Path` based on horizontal extent. The usual approach would be to do this yourself, since you presumably know the original X coordinate of each `Path` element, and you are graphing a _single-valued function_. IOW, it may be better for you to store your data in a custom format (one where you can remember the X coordinate), and create the `Path` only when rendering time comes around.

Comment: It is similar to what I have right now. Just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks for confirmation.